# Is it possible to add On Click Button method in a Fragment?

Tags: button, fragment, onclicklistener, buttonclick

i have added a button in a xml file ..now i want to open it in fragment ..
i am trying to show share option on button click but not findViewbyid working nor anything happen when click on button after RUN..
May be this is the code for sharing.. I am Confused..Please Help

I have Tried My Best..Any Help Will be Appreciated..Thanks to All Experts

**(XML Files)**

activity_main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_item_gray_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_item_gray_color"
        android:background="#302E2D"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_android" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_more :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
            android:text="Night Mode"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"></androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_share"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
            android:text="Share"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_option2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_share"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
            android:text="Recommend to friends"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_option3"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_option2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
            android:text="Get Free Islamic Apps"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_option4"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_option3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
            android:text="Rate and Feedback"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_option5"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_option4"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
            android:text="Help"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Example Text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**(Java Files)**

Main_Activity :

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new Home_Fragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem MenuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (MenuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new Home_Fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_settings:
                            selectedFragment = new More_Fragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

Fragment_More :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class More_Fragment extends Fragment {

    Button btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container,false);}





}
```

Even Tried This Code in **Fragment_More** But Failed

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class More_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private String a = "";
    private String b = "";

    private LinearLayout linear1;
    private Button btn_share;
    private TextView textview6;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container,false);}

    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {

        linear1 = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        btn_share = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
        textview6 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview6);

        btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                a = textview6.getText().toString();
                b = textview6.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("text/plain"); i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, a); i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share using"));
            }
        });
    }
    private void initializeLogic() { textview6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is How Its Done..Thanks A Million All Experts..

**Fragment_More.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class More_Fragment extends Fragment{

    private String a = "";
    private String b = "";

    private LinearLayout linear1;
    private Button btn_sharethis;
    private TextView text;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        btn_sharethis = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_shareme);
        text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview61);

        btn_sharethis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = text.getText().toString();
                b = text.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("text/plain"); i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, a); i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share using"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference your Button within your fragment you want to do it in onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container,false);
     btn_share = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
     btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                a = textview6.getText().toString();
                b = textview6.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("text/plain"); i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, a); i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share using"));
            }
        });
     return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Helping atleast the fragment is opening, But when i Click On Button <App Crashes> ..I am Stuck Please Help me.

Comment: What does the logs say? My solution wasn't complete, only exemplified the button initialization. In your onClick your for example referencing textview6. You need to initialize that the same way, so `textview6 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview6);`

Comment: Oh Very Well Sir..Thanks A Million.. Its Done..Thanks For Giving time..I Did it Like That..